# How do I display toasts from a thread without repeating code?

Tags: android, toast

<strike>Do I have to make a new runnable</strike>

How do I make toasts from inside a thread without spamming my thread with the code below

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, R.string.something, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //edit
  }
});
```

everythime i want to display a toast?

**here is my code**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doLogin();
            }
        }).start();
    }


public void doLogin() {
        username = teUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        password = tePassword.getText().toString().trim();
        if(username == "" || password == ""){
            displayToast("Enter a username and password");
            return;
        }
.
.
.
more toasts
```

**edit** I want to know how to call toasts from inside a thread efficiently. without creating an new runnable every time i want to display a toast

Answer (score 3):

`.show()` end of Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, R.string.something, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: it's not my question. I didn't ask why a toast wasn't showing. I am asking how to display toasts from a none UI thread efficiently

Comment: @user521180 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers